# Hot reload C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have a entity component system in place [C#] and i generate a visual studio solution on creating a new project in my application where user can  create their own components. When a user adds a new component in visual studio project , i need to detect this change , compile the solution and make that component visible in my application so that user can add it to an entity and edit it's property in the property grid [xceed wpf property grid] without closing my application. [Similar to what ECS game engines like Unity/Paradox/WaveEngine does]. Not sure about Unity , however, waveengine uses **roslyn** to achieve this if i am correct.

Need your inputs on various approaches to achieve this.

**Also, i see following changes :**

If a component is already added to an entity and is saved [serialized] , now i have edited that component and recompiled . How do i ensure that the previous entity/component that was already saved doesn't break? or how do i restore it? For ex : i have added a new property to my component. I need to ensure that entities already using this component have default values set for that property and saved unless user edits and saves it next time.

Comment: Depending on your case, the scripting API might be what you're looking for. You should ship it with your application, create the objects you need with it, and use them in your own application. Examples: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Thanks Josh !! Please correct me if i am wrong. From your suggestion what i understand is : 1. I have an Entity with collection of IComponent. 2. I create a new Component @ run time using scripting API. 3. I create instances of this component and add to my Entity. 4. Now I should be able to serialize my Entity along with its components. 5.Now i need to edit this component @ run time.For ex: Add a new field to type and update all existing components of this type with this new definition [I am not sure about this part how to implement this]. Any thoughts?